# How to prepare pairs of values with sed to loop over?

Tags: bash, sed, foreach

I wrote

```
for pair in $(my command | sed -En "s/my expression/\1 \2/p"); do
    echo $pair
done
```

but got every entry per line:

```
host
port
host 
port
...
```

while if I print

```
my command | sed -En "s/my expression/\1 \2/p"
```

I get

```
host port
host port
host port
...
```

How to prepare pairs of values correctly?

Comment: You should post a reproducible example because the answers may be incomplete or working partially for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using command substitution and not setting IFS, try:

```
IFS='\n'
for pair in $(my command | sed -En "s/my expression/\1 \2/p"); do
    echo $pair
done
```

The default is to split on space, tab and newline. Here, you only want to split on newline, so you need to set IFS to that as otherwise that means that will not work properly if pair contain space or tab characters

Comment: You need a literal newline, so either: `IFS=$'\n'`, or on a POSIX-only shell: `IFS='`⏎
`'`. See: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2141

Comment: Neither `$'\n'` nor `'\n'` worked. With `$'\n'`it started to split by lines, but pairs are still united.

Comment: Tested on ubuntu server 18.04 (Linux  4.15.0-52-generic) in bash. It works for me. But since you don't provide any reproducible example, I simply pasted the "host port" lines in a file and did for pair in $(cat file);do ....

Answer (score 1):

Simple reason for this is that,

```
for pair in $(…)
```

iterates over whitespace(which includes a single space as in your case) separations. As the commands in `$()` are evaluated in one go which provide a result to the `for` loop, it just sees the argument list you gave it. So before starting the `for` loop, set `IFS=$'\n'`.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for pair in $(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid `sed` if it's not a very simple replacement. `awk` is much more capable while also being more legible. This is a POSIX `awk` answer.

```sh
my command | awk '{ d="\n"; if (NR%2) d=" "; printf $0 d}'
```

However, you won't be able to retain the spacing if you put that into [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) (the `$(…)` formatting). To resolve that, consider a different pairwise delimiter, e.g. change `d=" "` to `d=":"`

```sh
for pair in "$(my command | awk '{ d="\n"; if (NR%2) d=":"; printf $0 d}')"; do
    echo $pair
done
```

If you actually want to do something with the different parts of the pair, do the whole thing in bash:

```sh
line_num=0
while IFS= read line; do
    line_num=$((line_num+1))
    if [ $((line_num%2)) = 1 ]; then
        host="$line"
    else
        port="$line"
        # do things with $host and $port here
        echo "$host $port"
    fi
done < <(my command)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to run `sed` *before* the `while read` loop.

```
my command |
sed -n 's/my expression/\1 \2/p' |
while read -r host port; do
    : something with "$host" and "$port"
done
```

This is portable all the way back to the original Bourne `sh`.

(Bash offers `while ... done <(process)` which has some additional benefits, but that's not portable with `sh`.)

Like another answer already points out,

```
for value in $(generate expressions); do
```

will parse the output from `generate expressions` into *tokens,* and loop over them one at a time. This is one of the reasons to [not read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), but of course, in this case, we are not even dealing with lines.

Perhaps also note the use of `read -r` (you basically always want this, unless you specifically the decidedly odd behavior with backslashes in the input of legacy `read`) and single quotes around the `sed` script.

I also removed the `-E` from your `sed` options, since in this example you are not using any regex syntax where this makes any difference (the ERE regex dialect which `-E` selects is more familiar and convenient than the default BRE, but `-E` is not a standard option).